# Using a Data Bound Collection of MenuItems in Multiple Views

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a toolbar usercontrol which includes some dynamically added menuitems. The menuitems are part of observable collections of controls in the data context of the usercontrol, and are bound to the items source of their "top level" menu items as shown in the code below.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <MenuItem x:Key="fileKey" x:Shared="False" Header="_File" ItemsSource="{Binding FileMenuItems}" />
        <MenuItem x:Key="viewKey" x:Shared="False" Header="_View" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewMenuItems}" />
...
```

Some of these top level menuitems are duplicated in multiple parts of the view in a primary dropdown menu as well as a main text menu bar.

```
<Menu Name="dropDownMenu">
    <MenuItem>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="fileKey" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="viewKey" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
...
<StackPanel x:Name="TextMenuPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Menu Name="File">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="fileKey" />
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```

The issue I am having is that if I open, say "File", from one menu, then the other menu, then attempt to open the first menu again it shows an empty box with no headers etc. of the original size of the menu, while the previously opened menu continues to display correctly if reopened.

How can I correctly show the bound menuitems in more than one place without breaking the view?